# AppCenter shows me a error when i make a build of my branch (xamarin forms proj)

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-app-center

Im working with xamarin forms, I am trying to generate a build for ios in app center, the code in vs for mac does not throw errors, which compiles and runs perfectly, but when I try to generate the build in app center (I linked my branch from bitbucket to app center) is showing me the following:

### [error]Xamarin.iOS task failed with error Error: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6_4_2/bin/msbuild failed with return code: 1. For guidance on setting up the build definition, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=760847.

### [section]Finishing: Build Xamarin.iOS solution

What is going on?

Comment: you need to actually look at the build logs to find the error

Comment: Try to remove delete the "bin" and "obj" folder and then try to make a build.